# Accidentally created git repo in home directory

Tags: linux, git

Somehow I made my home directory (~) a git repository.

`git status` returns all of the files in my directory, which I do not want to commit.

`git rm --cached -r *` is not what I want either.

How can I remove the repository without deleting all of the files?

Comment: Sounds like it iis time to go back to your trusty backup you made before embarking on such a large project.

Comment: Yes. Who knew I could code so quickly!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the .git directory from ~/.

Comment: `rm -rf .git/` it is!

Answer (score 0):

So, I did the same thing where every time I ran  it returned the whole directory listed within `/User/` and I made the mistake of running `git clean -f -d` on it yesterday but lo and behold, I deleted ALL my files!

Anyway, just a heads up to anyone who has this issue: `rm -rf .git/` when ran inside `~/` worked for me and I can now stop pulling my hair out about it.

Be careful with `git clean --` and if in doubt, talk to someone.